# Wordpress Uncode Theme Woocommerce Product Image Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem ,the product images are not showing up, if you check this product [link](https://stephanelegrand.com/product/whats-new-york/) you might see the images, but if you refresh they will disappear at some point.

The client is using **Uncode Visual Composer** to display the products.

I turned wp_debug true , and im not sure if the PHP error is the problem with this.

Here is a screenshot
[image]

The code from line 41/42.

```
if ($image_attributes->post_mime_type === 'image/gif' || $image_attributes->post_mime_type === 'image/url') $crop = false;
        $image_resized = uncode_resize_image($image_attributes->id, $image_attributes->guid, $image_attributes->path, $image_metavalues['width'], $image_metavalues['height'], 5, ($crop ? 5 / $thumb_ratio : null), $crop);
```

Comment: its may be a plugin issue ... try to contact its author